# python qt5 tab widget: how set tabs with table widget to full main window size?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt5, qtablewidget, qtabwidget

I'm new with qt5 in python and struggling al lot to get a decent layout in qt5.
Below you find my code to create the tabs with a table in it. The code works fine to set the data in each table. But the layout isn't what I want. Can someone help me to get it straight.
P.S. I don't have qt designer.

**The python code** This is what I tried.

```py
import sys
import locale
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QBrush, QColor, QWindow
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    # constructor
    def __init__(self, flnm, data):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.flnm = flnm
        self.setWindowTitle('Table View : ' + self.flnm)
        self.data = data
        self.ptabs = list(self.data.keys())

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.tabs = QTabWidget()
        self.tabs.setTabsClosable(True)
        self.add_tabs(self.ptabs, self.data)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tabs)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    # Fill table with data
    def set_table(self, headers, row_data, types):
        self.table_widget.setRowCount(len(row_data))
        self.table_widget.setColumnCount(len(row_data[0]))

        if len(row_data) > 0:
            self.table_widget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(headers)

            row_index = 0
            for row in row_data:
                col_index = 0
                for value in row:
                    typ = types.get(col_index, None)
                    if typ == 'float':
                        try:
                            strval = locale.format_string('%.3f', value, grouping=True)
                            item = QTableWidgetItem(strval)
                            if value < 0:
                                item.setForeground(QBrush(QColor('red')))
                        except:
                            item = QTableWidgetItem(str(value))
                        item.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignVCenter | Qt.AlignRight)
                    elif typ == 'integer':
                        try:
                            strval = locale.format_string(f'%.0f', value, grouping=True)
                            item = QTableWidgetItem(strval)
                            if value < 0:
                                item.setForeground(QBrush(QColor('red')))
                        except:
                            item = QTableWidgetItem(str(value))
                        item.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignVCenter | Qt.AlignRight)
                    elif typ == 'date_time':
                        #strval = dt.fromtimestamp(value)
                        item = QTableWidgetItem(str(value))
                    elif typ == 'string':
                        try:
                            item = QTableWidgetItem(value)
                        except:
                            continue
                    else:
                        item = QTableWidgetItem(value)
                    self.table_widget.setItem(row_index, col_index, item)
                    col_index += 1
                row_index += 1

    # method for adding the tabs with a table
    def add_tabs(self, ptabs, datd):
        if len(ptabs) > 0:
            for tab in ptabs:
                types = datd[tab]['types']
                headers = datd[tab]['headers']
                row_data = datd[tab]['row_data']
                self.tab = QTabWidget()
                self.tabs.addTab(self.tab, tab)

                self.table_widget = QTableWidget()
                self.table_widget.setParent(self.tab)

                self.set_table(headers, row_data, types)
                self.table_widget.resizeColumnsToContents()
                self.table_widget.resizeRowsToContents()
```

**This is what I expect.** Full size window (screen) table(s) but then in a tab as shown below.
[image]

**This is what I get on the moment**
[image]

The data for testing. file type JSON dictionary

```py
{
   "Blad1": {
      "types": {
         "0": "string",
         "1": "float",
         "2": "float",
         "3": "float",
         "4": "float",
         "5": "integer"
      },
      "headers": [
         "date",
         "open",
         "low",
         "high",
         "close",
         "volume"
      ],
      "row_data": [
         [
            "2015-11-20",
            18.18,
            18.0,
            18.43,
            18.35,
            38392898
         ],
         [
            "2015-11-23",
            18.45,
            18.215,
            18.7,
            18.61,
            3352514
         ],
         [
            "2015-11-24",
            18.7,
            18.37,
            18.8,
            18.8,
            4871901
         ],
         [
            "2015-11-25",
            18.85,
            18.77,
            19.5,
            19.45,
            4802607
         ],
         [
            "2015-11-26",
            19.48,
            19.41,
            19.67,
            19.43,
            1648481
         ],
         [
            "2015-11-27",
            19.45,
            19.255,
            19.79,
            19.65,
            1428854
         ],
         [
            "2015-11-30",
            19.74,
            19.55,
            19.94,
            19.88,
            5982957
         ],
         [
            "2015-12-01",
            19.9,
            19.6,
            19.95,
            19.7,
            1511970
         ],
         [
            "2015-12-02",
            19.645,
            19.52,
            19.89,
            19.8,
            4623032
         ],
         [
            "2015-12-03",
            19.75,
            19.185,
            19.94,
            19.35,
            1707701
         ],
         [
            "2015-12-04",
            19.4,
            19.28,
            19.585,
            19.425,
            1096498
         ],
         [
            "2015-12-07",
            19.5,
            19.425,
            19.85,
            19.7,
            2559985
         ],
         [
            "2015-12-08",
            19.75,
            19.05,
            19.75,
            19.185,
            975463
         ],
         [
            "2015-12-09",
            19.4,
            19.11,
            19.47,
            19.235,
            696757
         ],
         [
            "2015-12-10",
            19.26,
            19.25,
            19.555,
            19.31,
            726421
         ],
         [
            "2015-12-11",
            19.375,
            19.06,
            19.4,
            19.35,
            699670
         ],
         [
            "2015-12-14",
            19.35,
            19.15,
            19.59,
            19.19,
            536032
         ],
         [
            "2015-12-15",
            19.33,
            19.155,
            19.49,
            19.155,
            542349
         ],
         [
            "2015-12-16",
            19.24,
            19.07,
            19.33,
            19.19,
            549069
         ],
         [
            "2015-12-17",
            19.275,
            19.27,
            19.81,
            19.7,
            760246
         ],
         [
            "2015-12-18",
            19.65,
            19.55,
            20.0,
            20.0,
            1299310
         ],
         [
            "2015-12-21",
            19.91,
            19.82,
            20.0,
            19.96,
            692244
         ],
         [
            "2015-12-22",
            19.95,
            19.69,
            20.065,
            20.01,
            496124
         ],
         [
            "2015-12-23",
            20.1,
            20.09,
            20.415,
            20.395,
            512478
         ],
         [
            "2015-12-24",
            20.45,
            20.245,
            20.46,
            20.4,
            189821
         ],
         [
            "2015-12-28",
            20.4,
            20.2,
            20.45,
            20.26,
            140675
         ],
         [
            "2015-12-29",
            20.35,
            20.275,
            20.76,
            20.76,
            630806
         ],
         [
            "2015-12-30",
            20.71,
            20.57,
            20.8,
            20.795,
            310286
         ],
         [
            "2016-01-04",
            20.6,
            20.56,
            21.0,
            20.67,
            898265
         ],
         [
            "2016-01-05",
            20.87,
            20.55,
            20.9,
            20.63,
            847726
         ],
         [
            "2016-01-06",
            20.65,
            20.03,
            20.65,
            20.13,
            757729
         ],
         [
            "2016-01-07",
            19.965,
            19.425,
            19.965,
            19.695,
            1498763
         ],
         [
            "2016-01-08",
            19.9,
            19.835,
            20.2,
            19.97,
            801778
         ],
         [
            "2016-01-11",
            19.91,
            19.56,
            19.91,
            19.65,
            742877
         ],
         [
            "2016-01-12",
            19.62,
            19.4,
            19.795,
            19.43,
            1050981
         ],
         [
            "2016-01-13",
            19.53,
            19.415,
            19.86,
            19.425,
            643534
         ],
         [
            "2016-01-14",
            19.3,
            19.01,
            19.34,
            19.13,
            755248
         ],
         [
            "2016-01-15",
            19.16,
            18.525,
            19.2,
            18.55,
            1022030
         ],
         [
            "2016-01-18",
            18.515,
            18.08,
            18.7,
            18.08,
            1098012
         ],
         [
            "2016-01-19",
            18.5,
            18.25,
            18.75,
            18.655,
            814737
         ],
         [
            "2016-01-20",
            18.34,
            18.0,
            18.49,
            18.11,
            980031
         ],
         [
            "2016-01-21",
            18.15,
            17.95,
            18.36,
            18.15,
            905925
         ],
         [
            "2016-01-22",
            18.5,
            18.36,
            19.0,
            18.9,
            841434
         ],
         [
            "2016-01-25",
            19.19,
            18.915,
            19.25,
            19.105,
            635352
         ],
         [
            "2016-01-26",
            18.97,
            18.75,
            19.37,
            19.185,
            643071
         ],
         [
            "2016-01-27",
            19.2,
            18.985,
            19.42,
            19.055,
            631634
         ],
         [
            "2016-01-28",
            18.985,
            18.945,
            19.36,
            19.0,
            1105512
         ],
         [
            "2016-01-29",
            19.185,
            18.995,
            19.24,
            19.24,
            593734
         ],
         [
            "2016-02-01",
            19.44,
            19.21,
            19.505,
            19.22,
            614105
         ],
         [
            "2016-02-02",
            19.22,
            18.22,
            19.365,
            18.25,
            973538
         ],
         [
            "2016-02-03",
            18.35,
            17.975,
            18.39,
            18.0,
            996655
         ],
         [
            "2016-02-04",
            18.31,
            18.135,
            18.99,
            18.93,
            1537462
         ],
         [
            "2016-02-05",
            18.99,
            18.555,
            18.99,
            18.785,
            971200
         ],
         [
            "2016-02-08",
            18.97,
            17.31,
            18.97,
            17.45,
            1546073
         ],
         [
            "2016-02-09",
            17.5,
            15.915,
            17.75,
            16.27,
            2801400
         ],
         [
            "2016-02-10",
            16.41,
            16.165,
            17.47,
            17.085,
            1475325
         ],
         [
            "2016-02-11",
            17.0,
            16.35,
            17.385,
            16.86,
            1398721
         ],
         [
            "2016-02-12",
            15.9,
            15.225,
            16.69,
            16.605,
            4202723
         ],
         [
            "2016-02-15",
            17.06,
            17.015,
            17.45,
            17.26,
            1057664
         ],
         [
            "2016-02-16",
            17.5,
            16.805,
            17.65,
            17.035,
            1435767
         ],
         [
            "2016-02-17",
            16.485,
            16.15,
            17.14,
            16.51,
            2701741
         ],
         [
            "2016-02-18",
            17.095,
            16.875,
            17.43,
            17.095,
            2165956
         ],
         [
            "2016-02-19",
            17.2,
            17.01,
            17.4,
            17.1,
            838582
         ],
         [
            "2016-02-22",
            17.345,
            17.265,
            17.615,
            17.615,
            544539
         ],
         [
            "2016-02-23",
            17.455,
            17.41,
            18.05,
            17.565,
            612696
         ],
         [
            "2016-02-24",
            17.5,
            17.08,
            17.79,
            17.25,
            788044
         ],
         [
            "2016-02-25",
            17.4,
            17.28,
            18.14,
            18.0,
            750660
         ],
         [
            "2016-02-26",
            18.08,
            18.055,
            18.735,
            18.61,
            745206
         ],
         [
            "2016-02-29",
            18.4,
            18.03,
            18.51,
            18.24,
            670097
         ]
      ]
   },
   "Blad2": {
      "types": {
         "0": "string",
         "1": "float",
         "2": "float",
         "3": "float",
         "4": "float",
         "5": "integer"
      },
      "headers": [
         "date",
         "open",
         "low",
         "high",
         "close",
         "volume"
      ],
      "row_data": [
         [
            "2010-01-04",
            10.19,
            10.19,
            10.795,
            10.66,
            1052090
         ],
         [
            "2010-01-05",
            10.745,
            10.5,
            10.76,
            10.615,
            768369
         ],
         [
            "2010-01-06",
            10.57,
            10.56,
            10.86,
            10.825,
            887358
         ],
         [
            "2010-01-07",
            10.87,
            10.65,
            10.87,
            10.77,
            984580
         ],
         [
            "2010-01-08",
            10.77,
            10.675,
            10.87,
            10.79,
            274790
         ],
         [
            "2010-01-11",
            10.86,
            10.86,
            11.095,
            10.95,
            533742
         ],
         [
            "2010-01-12",
            11.015,
            10.605,
            11.04,
            10.67,
            353301
         ],
         [
            "2010-01-13",
            10.67,
            10.61,
            10.855,
            10.775,
            475021
         ],
         [
            "2010-01-14",
            10.8,
            10.62,
            10.805,
            10.725,
            397186
         ],
         [
            "2010-01-15",
            10.72,
            10.325,
            10.75,
            10.525,
            362661
         ],
         [
            "2010-01-18",
            10.48,
            10.13,
            10.595,
            10.53,
            438216
         ],
         [
            "2010-01-19",
            10.5,
            10.26,
            10.52,
            10.445,
            477906
         ],
         [
            "2010-01-20",
            10.48,
            10.46,
            11.0,
            10.74,
            932673
         ],
         [
            "2010-01-21",
            10.85,
            10.53,
            10.94,
            10.535,
            401719
         ],
         [
            "2010-01-22",
            10.45,
            10.15,
            10.52,
            10.31,
            402507
         ],
         [
            "2010-01-25",
            10.26,
            10.15,
            10.485,
            10.39,
            350598
         ],
         [
            "2010-01-26",
            10.345,
            10.15,
            10.39,
            10.335,
            186321
         ],
         [
            "2010-01-27",
            10.29,
            10.17,
            10.43,
            10.255,
            292840
         ],
         [
            "2010-01-28",
            10.38,
            10.28,
            10.53,
            10.325,
            338669
         ],
         [
            "2010-01-29",
            10.4,
            10.31,
            10.61,
            10.565,
            406514
         ],
         [
            "2010-02-01",
            10.545,
            10.31,
            10.67,
            10.575,
            330978
         ],
         [
            "2010-02-02",
            10.62,
            10.55,
            10.84,
            10.78,
            328143
         ],
         [
            "2010-02-03",
            10.79,
            10.73,
            10.89,
            10.775,
            208177
         ],
         [
            "2010-02-04",
            10.765,
            10.445,
            10.9,
            10.5,
            471353
         ],
         [
            "2010-02-05",
            10.34,
            9.77,
            10.35,
            9.94,
            775423
         ],
         [
            "2010-02-08",
            10.01,
            9.61,
            10.1,
            9.715,
            433498
         ],
         [
            "2010-02-09",
            9.6,
            9.531,
            9.987,
            9.87,
            428356
         ],
         [
            "2010-02-10",
            9.95,
            9.793,
            10.0,
            9.828,
            249427
         ],
         [
            "2010-02-11",
            9.887,
            9.62,
            10.0,
            9.691,
            408412
         ],
         [
            "2010-02-12",
            9.8,
            9.302,
            9.847,
            9.405,
            764981
         ],
         [
            "2010-02-15",
            9.405,
            9.353,
            9.585,
            9.48,
            193093
         ],
         [
            "2010-02-16",
            9.5,
            9.42,
            9.6,
            9.54,
            179712
         ],
         [
            "2010-02-17",
            9.601,
            9.601,
            9.86,
            9.787,
            342145
         ],
         [
            "2010-02-18",
            9.87,
            9.76,
            9.882,
            9.801,
            161145
         ],
         [
            "2010-02-19",
            9.787,
            9.718,
            9.95,
            9.91,
            352534
         ],
         [
            "2010-02-22",
            9.9,
            9.845,
            10.0,
            9.869,
            247318
         ],
         [
            "2010-02-23",
            9.973,
            9.849,
            10.0,
            9.88,
            336112
         ],
         [
            "2010-02-24",
            9.959,
            9.645,
            9.959,
            9.732,
            487428
         ],
         [
            "2010-02-25",
            9.88,
            9.784,
            10.19,
            10.055,
            920198
         ],
         [
            "2010-02-26",
            10.1,
            10.005,
            10.22,
            10.21,
            651660
         ],
         [
            "2010-03-01",
            10.2,
            10.175,
            10.38,
            10.35,
            584601
         ],
         [
            "2010-03-02",
            10.395,
            10.39,
            10.685,
            10.685,
            339538
         ],
         [
            "2010-03-03",
            10.7,
            10.6,
            10.89,
            10.845,
            533918
         ],
         [
            "2010-03-04",
            10.84,
            10.74,
            10.95,
            10.885,
            446942
         ],
         [
            "2010-03-05",
            10.89,
            10.89,
            11.1,
            11.025,
            494925
         ],
         [
            "2010-03-08",
            11.0,
            10.93,
            11.1,
            10.98,
            273210
         ],
         [
            "2010-03-09",
            10.98,
            10.8,
            10.98,
            10.88,
            235355
         ],
         [
            "2010-03-10",
            10.82,
            10.81,
            11.05,
            11.0,
            542717
         ],
         [
            "2010-03-11",
            10.95,
            10.91,
            11.6,
            11.44,
            950116
         ],
         [
            "2010-03-12",
            11.425,
            11.375,
            11.59,
            11.46,
            322906
         ],
         [
            "2010-03-15",
            11.49,
            11.165,
            11.49,
            11.235,
            308413
         ],
         [
            "2010-03-16",
            11.3,
            11.13,
            11.35,
            11.205,
            244175
         ],
         [
            "2010-03-17",
            11.22,
            11.18,
            11.395,
            11.215,
            326796
         ],
         [
            "2010-03-18",
            11.17,
            10.95,
            11.25,
            11.06,
            370445
         ],
         [
            "2010-03-19",
            11.11,
            10.905,
            11.15,
            10.945,
            648604
         ],
         [
            "2010-03-22",
            10.82,
            10.53,
            11.03,
            11.0,
            522460
         ],
         [
            "2010-03-23",
            11.135,
            11.13,
            11.545,
            11.515,
            628970
         ],
         [
            "2010-03-24",
            11.57,
            11.53,
            11.715,
            11.64,
            401246
         ],
         [
            "2010-03-25",
            11.62,
            11.57,
            11.94,
            11.87,
            496576
         ],
         [
            "2010-03-26",
            11.85,
            11.75,
            12.0,
            11.935,
            350853
         ],
         [
            "2010-03-29",
            12.0,
            11.845,
            12.1,
            11.945,
            442058
         ],
         [
            "2010-03-30",
            11.95,
            11.75,
            12.0,
            11.755,
            272615
         ],
         [
            "2010-03-31",
            11.775,
            11.61,
            11.875,
            11.81,
            319240
         ],
         [
            "2010-04-01",
            11.86,
            11.86,
            12.22,
            12.16,
            580117
         ],
         [
            "2010-04-06",
            12.25,
            12.23,
            12.68,
            12.6,
            604284
         ],
         [
            "2010-04-07",
            12.6,
            12.45,
            12.695,
            12.57,
            708197
         ],
         [
            "2010-04-08",
            12.5,
            12.3,
            12.54,
            12.38,
            611246
         ],
         [
            "2010-04-09",
            12.41,
            12.41,
            12.525,
            12.5,
            267080
         ],
         [
            "2010-04-12",
            12.56,
            12.525,
            12.615,
            12.55,
            330393
         ]
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: (1) Create a `QWidget`, set a layout on it, and then set it as the central widget. (2) Add the table and any other widgets/layouts to the central layout. (NB: *Do not attempt to add a layout to the main-window itself*).